# Cannot make a 3d `\mathfrak` label in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

Trying this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=1;
import three;
label("$\mathfrak g$",(0,0,0));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

After running it through `pdflatex` I invoke `asymptote` and get this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-12-17>
(C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\.tex File ignored)
(fraklab-1_.tex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file .aux.
! I can't write on file `.aux'.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...
l.10 \begin{document}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-C to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name
! Emergency stop.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...
l.10 \begin{document}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on .log.
    g=tex ? _texpath(s,p) : textpath(s,p);
     ^
C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_Label.asy: 664.6: texpath failed
```

Everything works fine without `\mathfrak`.

What can I do?

Comment: with usepackage("amssymb"); in the environment asy. And change settings.render=1, ; rendering is not as expected settings.render=4, is already better

Comment: @pascal974 Great, thanks! I believe it can be useful if you make your comment an answer. I for one would never expect that packages must be extra loaded inside the asy environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have to import the `mathfrak` module in the `asy` environment
- Change the `settings.render`

  ```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{asy}
   settings.outformat="pdf";
   settings.prc=false;
   // settings.render=1;
   // at least 4
   settings.render=10;
   import three;
   usepackage("amssymb");// <--- this line
   label("$\mathfrak g$",(0,0,0));
   \end{asy}
   \end{document}
  ```

Comment: For the setting render in the doc https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote_tutorial.pdf 3.4 High-resolution rasterized images